# How to inject `$attributes` value to anonymous blade component from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Suppose I have the following anonymous blade component called `badge`:

```php
@props(['text'])

<span {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'text-bold']) }}>
    {{ $text?? '-' }}
</span>
```

If I were to use it from a blade page, I can define the value of `$text` and define some additional class as well, as follows:

```php
<x-badge class="text-red" :text="This is dangerous" />
```

Now my question is: how can I do the above from controller? Using the code below...

```php
function index() {
    return view('components.badge', ['text' => 'This is dangerous', 'class' => 'text-red']);
}

// results
// <span class="text-bold">This is dangerous</span>
```

...will results in the `badge` component has `$text` of `This is dangerous`, but the `text-red` **is not** added to its class. I belive this is because the `class` passed to the view-component becomes a "property" instead of "class attribute", thus preventing it from being merged to its default class as defined in the `$attribute->merge(['class' => 'text-bold'])`.

A way around this is to change the `badge` component to become like this:

```php
@props(['text', 'class' => ''])         // <---- add `class` property with empty string as default

<span {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'text-bold '.$class]) }}>   // <---- print the `class` property directly here
    {{ $text?? '-' }}
</span>
```

However this feels like a trick instead of a proper way. So I'm looking a way to overcome this from the controller instead of the above way-around.

Your help means a lot to me. Thanks!